# Why is my Permissions page empty?

Tags: 9

We are developing a Drupal 9 site on Acquia. When I go to /admin/people/permissions there are no permissions listed. But when I go to /admin/people/roles I can edit the permissions on a given role and see all the permission checkboxes as normal.  /admin/people looks fine. Any clues as to what happened to the Permissions page?

Comment: I'd check the server error logs (or the watchdog entries list) to see if anything is crashing out.

Comment: Might also be a Drupal memory issue. Does the page fully load, but is missing permissions, or does the page load die before fully loading?

Comment: Since you can edit role permissions individually, I think this is most likely a memory issue or some other PHP limitation. Maybe something like [Filter permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/filter_perms) will help.

Comment: Literally what does /admin/people/permissions look like with this? Is there anything at all logged?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting blank page, wsod, on the permissions page (/admin/people/permissions).

So, i changed the below values in php.ini + Apache restart

max_input_vars = 3000

memory_limit = 512M

After changing the values in php.ini, make sure its reflected by pulling (/admin/reports/status/php) in there, you can also see which php.ini file is being used.

In my case: /admin/reports/status/php kept showing the old values even after Apache restart, so i had to do the following which solved it and forced the new values to take effect:

systemctl restart  php-fpm  (if you're using this )